# Sorting an IEnumerable collection with a virtual field of that collection

Tags: virtual, ienumerable, repository-pattern, foreign-key-relationship

I have a repository with a list of all content:

```
private Repository<Content> contentRepository
```

And I have a repository with a list of statistics for the content:

```
private Repository<ContentStatistic> statisticRepository
```

In the content model there is a ContentStatisticID which links the two classes as a foreign key

I have declared an IEnumerable called MostPopularContent and am trying to create a list of the 8 most watched videos as the statistics class also has other information like who liked it etc I left the view count outside the content.cs class

I have tried the following code but it is erroring out and I cant seem to get a workaround:

```
MostPopularContent = contentRepository.GetAll()
            .Join(statisticRepository.Get(s => s.Views != 0),
            c => c.ContentStatisticID,
            s => s.ContentStatisticID,
            (c, s) => new Content()
            {
                ContentID = c.ContentID,
                Views = s.Views
            })
            .Take(8)
            .ToList();
```

When I run this I get the following error:

**Unable to create a constant value of type 'Data.ContentStatistic'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was occurring because I had not set initialized lazy loading and so the virtual properties were always being returned as nil. I overcame this problem by adding the following line of code to my ViewModel:

```
this.dbcontext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

Within the View itself I also had a series of nested queries for some of the more complex models and had to add the following segment to the connection string:

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```